# Getting DLL error with 'jupyter lab' command in Anaconda Installation

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Getting DLL error with 'jupyter lab' command in Anaconda Installation:

Details for system:

- conda 4.5.11
- Python 3.7.0
- jupyter 4.4.0

Height of weirdness is that I am able to launch jupyter lab from Anaconda Navigator, but '**jupyter lab**' is not working and throwing below exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ML\installed_tools\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-lab.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jupyterlab_server import slugify, WORKSPACE_EXTENSION
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .app import LabServerApp
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .server import ServerApp
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py", line 32, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.serverapp import ServerApp, aliases, flags      # noqa
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 46, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 27, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "c:\ml\installed_tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I have posted this question, but now I also got a solution for the same.

Please add following in the path variable, it will be resolved thereafter (I just checked):

- C:\ML\installed_tools\anaconda3 (was already present)
- C:\ML\installed_tools\anaconda3\Scripts (was already present)
- **C:\ML\installed_tools\anaconda3\Library\bin** (**added now**)
- **C:\ML\installed_tools\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin** (**added now**)

Comment: what is the path variable and how do you add to the path variable?